# How to set value of input field like user typing

Tags: javascript, html

Such as: When I sets the value of a text field to “abc[…]xyz” with JS, the text field currently looks like [abcdefg] on the page. I wants it to look like [tuvwxyz], the same way it would look if the user typed “abc[…]xyz” out with their keyboard.Any good idea?BTW, the input field can't lost focus.

Comment: I mean the value is too long for input to hold. How to hanlde the excess part?

Comment: This is the question you asked previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536083/how-to-move-the-text-in-input-using-js